# нужно вывести текст между кавычками на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть к примеру текст:

```
+CGCONTRDP: 1,6,"internet","10.112.24.149.255.0.0.0","10.112.24.150","80.255.64.24","80.255.64.23","","",0,,0,,0
```

объясняю что тут и куда:

```
+CGCONTRDP: 1,6,"APN","ip.ip.ip.ip.mask.mask.mask.mask","шлюз.шлюз.шлюз.шлюз","dns1.dns1.dns1.dns1","dns2.dns2.dns2.dns2","","",0,,0,,0
```

нужно что бы выводились отдельно `АPN`, `ip`, `mask`, `шлюз`, `dns1`, `dns2`.

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82+%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85)

Comment: я это видел но я хотел бы иметь код потому что я с тем способом игрался долго и то что надо не вышло

Comment: нет, просто спешил того указал что было

Comment: Не нужно все подряд метки указывать. Достаточно было метки python в данном случае.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вам покажу откуда начать элементарно. Просто используйте `split`:

```py
text = '+CGCONTRDP: 1,6,"internet","10.112.24.149.255.0.0.0","10.112.24.150","80.255.64.24","80.255.64.23","","",0,,0,,0'
_, _, АPN, ip_mask, шлюз, dns1, dns2, *_ = text.split(',')
```

Разделить `ip` и `mask` будет уже сложнее, лучше использовать регулярное выражение. Впрочем, может быть всю строку лучше сразу регуляркой разделить на составляющие.

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться